# Create configMap with the key as variable(Kubernetes)

Tags: shell, kubernetes, kubectl

I want to create config map from file with key as value of variable from kubectl tool

However,

```
MY_VARIBLE="something"
kubectl create configmap myconfigmap --from-file=${MY_VARIBLE}=myfile.json
```

does not return anything and configmap is not created

```
kubectl create configmap myconfigmap --from-file=something=myfile.json
```

works correctly.
How can I workaround it? Thanks!!

Comment: Have you tried using double quote `"` to prevent globbing or word splitting? `kubectl create configmap myconfigmap --from-file="$MY_VARIBLE"=myfile.json`

Comment: I can't reproduce this error (in bash at least) - are you sure that `MY_VARIBLE` is defined and accessible to kubectl? Also what shell are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all!
My real problem was that MY_VARIABLE had value with ":"
After replacing ":" with "-" everything started working correctly in any case from above